# How to zoom world HDR image?

Tags: camera, world

I use environment texture as a "material" for my world to produce light and a nice background. When I move my camera to zoom in, the objects zoom but the background doesn't zoom. The only way to get around this is to change the Focal Length of the camera but it is not practical because it's very hard to do with many camera movements. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by this question, what is the actual problem? How does your scene look and how should it look? Also resizing HDRI is a bit not working, because environment texture is mapped to a theoretical sphere of infinite radius, changing of its scale would not change the angular increments of its spherical projection, and would thus not be perceived as different in scale... If you however want a specific part of your HDRI to be a part of your background, you need to add a mapping node to your texture and scale/rotate it (if you scale it too much you will see distortion)